# android:theme="@style/..." doenst take background

Tags: android, android-layout

I got the following background for an edit text:

edit_text_rounded_white.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#66c6c6c6"/>
        <stroke android:width="0.1dp"
            android:color="#66c6c6c6"/>
       <corners android:radius="40dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

in my styles.xml I define the following:

```
<style name="editText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_rounded_white</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/edit_text_cursor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/transparentWhite50</item>
</style>
```

When I set the style via: `style="@style/editText"` for my editTexts it takes the background but doesnt take the colorControl I set. When I set the style via `android:theme="@style/editText"` it takes the colorControls but doesnt show the background image. I already tried `src` and `windowBackground` instead of `background` in the style file.

Any ideas how achieve both? Showing background and the colorControls?

Answer (score 0):

Split your style into two:

```
<style name="editTextStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_rounded_white</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/edit_text_cursor</item>
</style>

<style name="editTextTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/transparentWhite50</item>
</style>
```

And then apply both to your view:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:theme="@style/editTextTheme"
    style="@style/editTextStyle"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I got a bit closer to where I want to be: the background is showing and the item `colorControlNormal` works. But the item `colorControlActivated` is still not showing (i.e. the "underline" of an editText when not focused)